# Multiple mapviews android v2

Tags: android, google-maps

I want a mapview which shows the map scaled down and another mapview 
which shows the map scaled up. 
Any way I can implement this?

Tks

Comment: what do you mean by scaled up and scaled down?

Comment: different levels of zoom but showing same geographic area.

Comment: two maps coordinated. a first one more small than the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map1"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

  <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map2"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And in MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
// Google Map
private GoogleMap googleMap1,googleMap2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        // Loading map
        initilizeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/**
 * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
 * */
private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap1 == null) {
        googleMap1 = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map1)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap1 == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }

      if (googleMap2 == null) {
        googleMap2 = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map2)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap2 == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();
}
 }
```

Comment: OMG! I will try and then i give you some feedback. Tell me one thing, if its possible: i want to define that one of the maps is of the size (width, height-width) of the other map. i want that the maps arent overlaid.

Comment: Ok. It doenst work. Only appear one map. Please help

Comment: Done. It's working. I specify mannualy the height and width. Thank you. Save my day